# Creating multiple libraries from common codebase

Tags: android, libraries

Is it possible to create multiple libraries with different functionalities from a common code base? I'd like to create multiple .jar files within a single Android library project. The goal would be that some users get access to only a subset of the functionality and more privileged users can access the whole library.

Comment: This way requires more than one Android library project, but if you go that way you could layer things like this:

[Base library] <-- [Pro library]

You can have the pro library refer to the base library so you can use that as a common code base and share code.

Comment: In fact, I want to remove specific functions from a class and define at build time which version should be build (the more comfortable solution would be to build all versions at each build). So the functions should be excluded from build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [Apache Antenna](http://antenna.sourceforge.net/wtkpreprocess.php) to preprocess the file and do conditional compilation. You'll need to use Apache Ant to build if you go this route. See these resources:

- [Android Ant tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildAnt/article.html)
- [Managing projects from the command
  line](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html)
- [Building from the command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

Another way is to use Git branches, with a master branch containing the base functionality and a child branch containing the extra functionality. Then when you want to build one or the other, you just switch branches. The [Git SCM book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) has some good info on how to work with your child branches.